# FindArgMin gives error message, the function value is not a real number at particular number

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
CC = {{- w^2 + 2 (k1/m1) (1 - Cos[x]) + 
 k21 (k1/m1), -k21 (k1/m1)}, {-(k21 k1/m2), -w^2 + (k21 k1/m2) }};

U = Solve[Det[CC] == 0, w];

FindArgMin[Re[U[[4]]] /. {m1 -> 0.0295, m2 -> 0.38288, k1 -> 20616702, x -> [Pi]}, {k21, 5}]
```

> FindArgMin::nrnum: The function value Re[w->80263.6] is not a real
>   number at {k21} = {5.}.

Here CC is a 2x2 matrix and U is equation in w after equating determinant of CC to 0.
 When I tried to find minimum value for k21 for given values of remaining variables I'm getting the above mentioned error even though it is clear that the value is real. (I tried to get an expression in remaining variables rather than numbers couldnt get it thats why tried to get numerically)
Please let me know the reason behind the value not real error in `FindArgMin`.
Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706

Comment: 1. Why not use `Eigenvalues[]` on your matrix, and then take the square root of the result? 2. Are you sure you're supposed to have a minimum?

Comment: Eigenvalues[] does not provide the frequencies in terms of the rest of the variables. I tried it just now but as w is already in the function I am getting expression in terms of w only. Thanks for the comment.
Yes I believe I should get a value for say k21 for the minimum value of the function as I had used Manipulate to see the trend with the variation, I wanted to have an analytical expression, thats why tried to minimize the function value in order to get the expression for parameters

Comment: You are basically trying to solve the equation `Det[{{2 (k1/m1) (1 - Cos[x]) + k21 (k1/m1), -k21 (k1/m1)}, {-(k21 k1/m2), (k21 k1/m2)}} - w^2 IdentityMatrix[2]]` for `w`; this is entirely equivalent to getting the two eigenvalues of that matrix, and then taking the positive and negative square roots of those two eigenvalues, for a grand total of four solutions.